# How to start (from text) and end (to text) for string

Tags: javascript

How to search for word and start with it the string, and search for another word for end the string, for example:

```
var string = "Hello whole world";
```

start with "Hello" and end with "world"

so it will be:

```
var string = " whole ";
```

hope my question is clear

Comment: Where did you get stuck when you tried to write this script yourself?

Comment: is there an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findBetween(text, start, end) {
    var startIndex = text.indexOf(start);
    var endIndex = text.lastIndexOf(end);

    if (startIndex === -1) {
        throw new Error("Start string not found.");
    } else if (endIndex === -1) {
        throw new Error("End string not found.");
    }

    startIndex += start.length;

    if (startIndex > endIndex) {
        throw new Error("Start found after end!");
    }

    return text.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
}

console.log(findBetween("Hello whole world", "Hello", "world"));

// Output:
//  whole
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = "Hello whole world";
var re = /^\w+\s+(.*)\s+\w+$/;
var result = re.exec(text);
alert(result[1]);
```

Comment: its work but how can I customize the start and end words?

Comment: @anmml That wasn't part of the original question.  You could do `var start = "Hello"; var end = "world"; var re = new RegExp("^"+start+"\s+(.*)\s+"+end+"$");`

Comment: I also believe this alerts "whole" instead of " whole ".

Comment: @smarx I believe I've wasted enough time on a question that's probably a duplicate and could be solved by reading a basic regex tutorial